# Selectively Kick Out Logged-In Users After Banning Them

Tags: php, session, cakephp

Hello StackOverflow Community:

Here is a tricky situation. Suppose that 20 users are *logged-in* to my webapp and I, the admin, (from a different computer and browser) ban 3 of them, how then do I kick out those 3 logged-in users that I just banned? It seems to be a matter of deleting their sessions/cookies, but how do I know which sessions to delete/invalidate and how to access them?

Just so you know, this project is in CakePHP and I'm using Memcache as the engine to store sessions. I already tried an option discussed in the cakephp channel that goes like this:

---

1. When user log-ins, his session_id (e.g. sd19eIVasdokja021dnasd) is stored in memcached along with his user id (e.g. the one in db: 323). This way, the user's db record is associated with his session_id within the server. Some code:
   `Cache::write('user_session_id_' . $this->Auth->user('id'), $this->Session->id());`
2. After the model sets the user's banned column to 1, I lookup if a Memcache key with the user's id exists, from which I retrieve the session id. I then delete the Memcache key: 

   `if ($this->save(array('User' => array('id' => $userId, 'banned' => 1)), false)) {

   $userSessionId = Cache::read('user_session_id_' . $userId);

   if ($userSessionId !== false) {

       Cache::delete($userSessionId);

       Cache::delete('user_session_id_' . $userId);

   }
   }`
3. It doesn't work, the user is still logged-in. I'm very sure I have to destroy/invalidate cookies though, in which case there is probably no way to alter other users cookies, right?

---

**FOLLOWUP AND SOLUTION:**

I was able to solve this by following this...
[Remotely destroy a session in php (user logs in somewhere else)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443355/remotely-destroy-a-session-in-php-user-logs-in-somewhere-else)

...and also this (a bit pseudo-code within the `User` model that actually evolved from my point number two above)(Note that my point number one listed above is also needed, due to line six below):

```
foreach ($bannedUsers as $userId) {  
    if ($this->save(array('User' => array(  
        'id' => $userId,  
        'banned' => 1, 
        'ban_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))), false)) {  
            $userSessionId = Cache::read('user_session_id_' . $userId);  
            if ($userSessionId !== false) {  
                $Session->id($userSessionId);  
                $Session->write('Auth', '');  
                Cache::delete('user_session_id_' . $userId);  
            }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Is the user still logged in after they refresh the page?

Comment: Yes. They can still navigate the page and do whatever they want until they manually logout via the app's links/menus (which is a problem because this app handles some monetary transactions).

Comment: Won't deleting the session from memcache just make the cache grab the session again from the database? I think you should delete from both the cache and the database.

Comment: Sessions are not stored in db, but only in browser (i.e. cookie) and memcache. Sorry if I confused you.
(Btw, the user's db record must not be deleted after the ban is effected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be doing something wrong with your app. The idea of the SESSION/COOKIE system is that the SESSION id stored is matched at the beginning of each request made to the server with the COOKIE that the browser sends. If they don't match, the app simply exits and shows the logon page. Thus, if you are able to delete the SESSION id correctly, there is no way that a particular user is not logged off unless **you are not checking the SESSION/COOKIE match that you should at the first line of every page**.

Comment: Thank you. This makes a lot of sense. But from the code above, the Memcached sessions somehow are not being deleted. Ufff... gonna have to debug and debug until I find why those memcached keys still remain.

Comment: Just for testing, I stopped the Memcached service totally while logged-in and the app DID kick me out. But for some reason, I cannot delete the memcached sessions. I put some test code and found that cakephp's Cache::delete destroys cache keys that were set with the same class (i.e. Cache::write), but not cache keys that are solely sessions. :|

Comment: Marking this answer as the valid, because although it didn't provide the exact solution, it pointed me in the direction of seeking the solution, which was to associate the user's session id with his database record, so that when that record was banned, I looked up the session id, set it, and then empty it. See my original post for this.