# Remotely logging out inactive users

Tags: php, session

Is it possible to remotely log an inactive user out? I manage an app which is used to monitor employees. The app monitors a bunch of things in real time such as who's online, who's on break, who's done this, who's done that.. sometimes people don't logout when they leave, so I was wondering if it's possible to have build a functionality that would let admin remotely kill a user's session without losing their own session data.

I suppose I could.. store all admin session data in a temporary database row, then call the user-to-be-logged-out's session id from a database and then do something like this..

```
session_id($old_session_id);
session_start();
session_destroy();
```

(which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443355/remotely-destroy-a-session-in-php-user-logs-in-somewhere-else))

and then restart the session and load up the old session variables from the temp row...

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not session_write_close() followed by session_start()?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I will prefer to use Database Session Management for fulfill this scenario. In that case admin just need to remove particular row for specific user from session table. And User will be session out, As your application will check session from DB not from normal session cookie.

Comment: thanks for the input. unfortunately the application is already built and relies heavily on PHP sessions.

Answer (score 1):

During each login set session start time and use following script to monitor:

```
<?php
session_start();
$TimeOutMinutes = 15; // This is your TimeOut period in minutes
$LogOff_URL = "login.php"; // If timed out, it will be redirected to this page

$TimeOutSeconds = $TimeOutMinutes * 60; // TimeOut in Seconds
if (isset($_SESSION['SessionStartTime'])) {
    $InactiveTime = time() - $_SESSION['SessionStartTime'];
    if ($InActiveTime >= $TimeOutSeconds) {
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: $LogOff_URL");
    }
}
$_SESSION['SessionStartTime'] = time();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, cool solution but I feel it's a little redundant as this functionality is alreay built into PHP. to change the session timeout I could just as easily change the setting in php.ini