# Laravel - destroy existing sessions on login

Tags: php, session, authentication, laravel

Is there a way to check if a user already has a valid session on a different machine?

What I want to do is when a user logs in, destroy an other sessions which they may already have, so that if they forget to logout from a computer say on campus or at work, and then they log in at home, it will  destroy those other 2 sessions so they are no longer logged in?

Facebook employs this in some way.

My only thoughts so far is something to this effect:

```
$user = User::find(1); // find the user
Auth::login($user); // log them in 
Auth::logout(); // log them out hoping that it will destroy all their sessions on all machines
Auth::login($user); // log them in again so they have a valid session on this machine
```

I have not had the chance to test this, and I do not know if `Auth::login($user);` will destroy all sessions for that user, or only the current one.

Thanks!

Comment: Laravel does not have built-in support for this. The login/logout auth methods only apply to the current session.

Comment: You will not be able to use that. It will only do it for that particular Session which is saved in the browser when you login.

Comment: Might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443355/remotely-destroy-a-session-in-php-user-logs-in-somewhere-else  I know Laravel has support for database sessions so what you can do is when a user is logging in, check the table for that user and destroy the session for that id.

Comment: Thats unforunate. Ill checkout that link, however i wasn't looking to move to database sessions as the default file based sessions seem to be working just fine. Maybe I will develop something that will find the users sessions in the files, and destroy them if they exist. But that might be exspensive to have running everytime a user logs in. We'll see. Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: After reading that link, I might be able to just hold onto the session_id's associated with a user when they log in, then when the user logs in from a new location, as the link describes, switch to the old sessions, destroy them, then switch back to / create a new session for this newest location. Assuming laravel will work fine with the standard php sessions functions.

Comment: Have since moved to datbase sessions due to a unrelated issue so will most likely implement some kind of support for this as 315900 suggested. Other issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767246/laravel-high-cpu-load-using-file-based-sessions

Answer (score 6):

You can save a session_id within a user model, so that:

1. When logout event is fired (auth.logout) you would clear it.
2. When new logging event is fired you can check if attribute session_id is not null within the user model.
3. If it's not - destroy previous session by:

`Session::getHandler()->destroy($user->session_id);`

`$user->session_id = Session::getId();`

Hope that would help!

Comment: I would have to persist this session id in the database for the given user model right? or would the existing user model be retrieved from memory (my understanding is that after the page load that user object in memory would be destroyed). I've since moved to database sessions so i'm going to work with that but ide like to understand this method.

Comment: Yes, with this example you would have to persist last session id in the database in the user model.

Answer (score 4):

I realise this is an old question, but there is now a method in laravel 5.6 that does exactly this, so it may be useful for someone coming to this later.  You can also retro-fit this method to earlier versions of laravel very easily.

See the docs at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#invalidating-sessions-on-other-devices

I had the same use case as you (log out all other devices on log-in).  I overrode the default login method to add my own custom logic (first copying the default login method from vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php)

In that method, there is the line `if ($this->attemptLogin($request))` - within this, before the return statement, add your call to logoutOtherDevices, as below

```
if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {

        //log out all other sessions
        Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request->password); //add this line

        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
}
```

Also ensure you have un-commented the `Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession` middleware in your app/Http/Kernel.php, as per the docs

(note that I haven't tested the above code as I was using an older version of laravel that doesn't have this method, see below).  This should work in 5.6 though.

## Older Laravel versions

I was actually using laravel 5.5, so didn't have access to this handy method.  Luckily, it's easy to add.
I opened a laravel 5.6 project and copied the logoutOtherDevices method from vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php - for reference I have pasted below

```
/**
 * Invalidate other sessions for the current user.
 *
 * The application must be using the AuthenticateSession middleware.
 *
 * @param  string  $password
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @return null|bool
 */
public function logoutOtherDevices($password, $attribute = 'password')
{
    if (! $this->user()) {
        return;
    }

    return tap($this->user()->forceFill([
        $attribute => Hash::make($password),
    ]))->save();
}
```

I then copied this into my LoginController - it could go somewhere else of your choice, but I've put it here for ease / laziness.  I had to modify it slightly, as below (`$this->user()` becomes `Auth::user()`)

```
 /**
 * Invalidate other sessions for the current user.
 * Method from laravel 5.6 copied to here
 *
 * The application must be using the AuthenticateSession middleware.
 *
 * @param  string  $password
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @return null|bool
 */
public function logoutOtherDevices($password, $attribute = 'password')
{
    if (! Auth::user()) {
        return;
    }

    return tap(Auth::user()->forceFill([
        $attribute => Hash::make($password),
    ]))->save();
}
```

I can then call this method in my login method, as specified earlier in my answer, with a slight adjustment - `$this->logoutOtherDevices($request->password);`

If you want to test this locally, it seems to work if you open your site on a normal and an incognito window.  When you log in on one, you'll be logged out on the other - though you'll have to refresh to see anything change.

Answer (score 3):

I hope you will see this job:

```
Session::regenerate(true);
```

a new session_id be obtained.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best answer, but first thing that came to my mind was lowering the timeout on the session.

In app->config->session.php there's a setting for both lifetime and expire_on_close (browser).

I'd try looking into that for now, and see if someone else comes up with something better.

Comment: There actually lies the cause of my problems. We want the sessions to last for 1 week, and not destroy on browser close. So we have the settings set appropriately to accomplish this in app->config->session.php. But becaues of this long lasting persistant session, I was hoping I would also be able to accomplish what I described in my  question, however that doesn't seem to be the case.