# Remove old sessions on login in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, session

How can I remove all expired user sessions from DB on login event ? I delete user session after log out. But sometimes a log out button not clicked and session expires and stay in DB.

I need delete all sessions from any machines for current user on user login event.

It possible or not in laravel 5.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

1. **Before User login**, check for any existing sessions in database for same user. One architectural assumption here, all existing sessions should be expired and need to be deleted.
2. If any exists, delete them.
3. Make sure you create/insert entry for current login after you delete existing/expired sessions.

For more information, you can check [**`this question and relevant answers`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574114/laravel-destroy-existing-sessions-on-login).