# How can i close current session in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to close current session. I'm trying implement logic when user log in through another device (another browser), all session with your id will close and when he will log in through old browser he will go to the authorization page. Ho can i do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - destroy existing sessions on login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574114/laravel-destroy-existing-sessions-on-login)

Comment: Session::getHandler()->destroy just delete session. But i need that closed session with user_id was in my database and create new session. I need it cus i want to know, how many times user does he come on my website and how long. Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to logout from all other devices except the current browser then you can follow the below steps:

**Step1:** Uncomment the line `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class` from `$middlewareGroups` property in `app/Http/Kernel.php` file because this is the middleware that manages the user `sessions` in Laravel.

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        ...
    ],
    ...
];
```

**Step2:** Next, you can use `logoutOtherDevices` method on the `Auth facade` which takes user’s password as its only argument. In your `LoginController`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
protected function authenticated($request, $user) { 
    Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request("password")); //add this
}
```

Comment: I did everything you said but it doesn't work. I think i do something wrong. 
i use my custom middleware in which i check Auth::check() and if false redirect to loginController.
In my loginController i use 
    public function login(Request $request) {
        if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request->email, 'password'=>$request->password])) {
            Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request->password);
        } else {
            return 'Вы ввели неверный логин или пароль';
        }
    }

Comment: i understand. This method work in laravel 6.x but my laravel version is 5.8