# Perform queries/tasks on specific users

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

I got a user system, with session for both their username and ID. I also got a field in my users table named `user_locked` which determines if the user's account is locked or not (if it's locked; they can't log in).

Recently I added a feature on my site where it allows me to lock users easily by one click, and I then got the idea: **is it possible to force that specific user to get logged out (make his/her session/cookies get destroyed) while leaving everyone elses unharmed?**

Is it possible? If it is, how would I do?

Thanks.

Comment: You could save a logged user's session id in your database upon login and then destroy it whenever and however you want. Relevant: [Stack QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443355/remotely-destroy-a-session-in-php-user-logs-in-somewhere-else)

Comment: Surely this question would be better titled "Can I force logout of a specific user on ___xxx___", where ___xxx___ is the system you are using to manage user sessions (which is unclear to me).

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be:

1. User logs in
2. You start a session for him and store whatever session variables you want
3. You store this session's ID in a table at your database with user id/username info
4. Whenever you want to destroy his session and log him out you follow this routine:

   ```
   // old_session_id will be retrieved from your database table for
   // this current user that you want to force log off
   session_id($old_session_id);
   session_start();
   session_destroy();
   ```

[Destroy php session remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443355/remotely-destroy-a-session-in-php-user-logs-in-somewhere-else)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - I have a row in my users table called "users" where I store the session that sets when the user logs in and when I run this nothing seem to happen.

Comment: Post relevant code to inspect how you are trying to tackle this.